# SSRS Bubble Chart with X Axis "Swim Lane"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, bubble-chart

**What The Customer Wants**

I have a customer that wants to have a bubble chart but with the bubbles in "swim lanes". So for example lets say the bubbles represent projects and each project is in a Phase (Phase 1, Phase 2, Phase 3). So in the image below (given by the customer) pretend that each space between the vertical dotted lines are the "swim lanes". The first swim lane would be phase 1, the second phase 2, and the third phase 3:

[image]

**What I Tried To Do To Solve The Problem**

I was thinking in my data query that I could dynamically create the X coordinates by sorting everything by phase and then for all the phase 1 projects giving it a number between 0 and 1 (so 0.2, 0.4, 0.6) and all the phase 2 projects a number between 1 and 2 (1.2, 1.4, 1.6), and all the phase 3 projects a number between 2 and 3.

That would then put all the projects on the X axis and all the phase 1 projects would be there between 0 and 1, all the phase 2 between 2 and 3 etc as seen below:

[image]

So this all works fine. The problem is, I want to change the X axis label so that if it's between 0 and 1 it says "Phase 1", between 1 and 2 "Phase 2" etc. I tried to change the label on the Category Group to be the phase, but it still just shows the X axis number.

Is there a way to do that? Is there a better way for me to accomplish this, or is it not even doable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the Axis Number Format to: 'Phase '0

Then I would set the Axis interval to 1.